# Magento 2 cannot enable caches

Tags: magento2, cache, admin-panel

I am not able to enable the Caches anymore, I am not in **Production Mode** and I read that the **Cache options are not available in Production Mode**, but:

```
 bin/magento deploy:mode:show
```

Shows I am not in production.

So what is this?

Comment: Can you clarify what your issue is?

Comment: `bin/magento deploy:mode:show` show what?

Answer (score 1):

There could be an error with one of your modules that is preventing the cache from being enabled.

try doing a `bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then try to enable cache.

Comment: I did so, no change.

Comment: I enabbled the cache by comandline:      php bin/magento cache:status
php bin/magento cache:enable config     
     php bin/magento cache:enable full_page          but its not answering the question.